# Is it safe to put the reCaptcha private key in html page?

Tags: html, recaptcha, private-key

Everyone can see my HTML code and accordingly my  reCaptcha private key. Is it a safe thing?

Comment: I would guess the clue is in the word "private". If a key is visible to everyone, it's not really private any more, is it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reCAPTCHA docs:

> The secret key authorizes communication between your application
>   backend and the reCAPTCHA server to verify the user's response. The
>   secret key needs to be kept safe for security purposes.
>
> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: No.

As you said everything is public on your page and even with a lot of obfuscation it is always possible to retrieve it.